# Error conexión mysql local

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Al intentar conectarme a la base local de mysql me arroja el siguiente mensaje:

> Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to
>   server at 127.0.0.1:3306:   Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES)

- Info
  Estoy intentando conectarme desde el workbench.
  El servidor mysql local está corriendo.

Alguna solución?.

Comment: Saludos deberias verificar primero tus credenciales sea por consola o phpmyadmin luego con estas ya verificadas intentarlas en mysqlworkbench

Comment: Parece que tu acceso no requiere contraseña o la escribiste mal

Comment: También pensé que podría ser que no tiene contraseña pero la estoy escribiendo bien y me arroja este mensaje `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)` . Lo otro es que solo a las bases locales no puedo ingresar, tengo agregada una base de internet y conecta sin drama

Comment: saludos debes verificar que la contraseña que estas ingresando para conectarte sea la correcta, si no configuraste ninguna contraseña al instalar el MySQL deja la contraseña vacía, espero sea de ayuda.

Comment: Ya validé eso. Mira los comentarios de la pregunta.

Comment: es la unica forma, o que tu servidor MYSQL este apagado.

Comment: Está encendido el servidor

Comment: entonces te estas equivocando en la contraseña o en el usuario no hay de otra, prueba con el usuario root sin password, de lo contrario no puedes acceder sin los datos de login, tendrias que reinstalar el servidor mysql.

Comment: Dale intentaré reinstalando, lo demás ya lo intenté

Comment: Una consulta usas linux o windows

Comment: Desde phpMyAdmin accedes normal?

Comment: Estoy usando linux

Comment: Finalmente tuve que forzar una desinstalación del mysql e instalar nuevamente. no encontré otra forma de hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

tuve el mismo problema con **MySQL versión 8.0.23**.

Lo solucione de la siguiente manera:

1- Abriendo nuevamente el **instalador msi** para Windows.

2- En **MySQL Server** hice click en "**Reconfigurar**".

3- Luego hice click en los pasos siguientes hasta llegar a "**Cuentas y Roles**" y ahí configure la **contraseña de "root"**

4- Por ultimo en **SQL Workbench**, entre a **Manage Server Conections** y hice click en "**store in Vault..**" donde **introduje la misma contraseña que en el paso 3**

PD: Este procedimiento también crea el **Servicio de MySQL** en Windows lo que también ayuda a solucionar este problema.

Espero que sea de utilidad